# React this.props.id is undefined in part of class

Tags: reactjs, axios, this, state

In my React application I need the userId in the Timeline class to get the posts from a user, but React says that it's undefined.

If I say in the rendered part

### { this.props.id }

Than it will show the right id..

I already tried every solution that I could possibly find on the internet.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Timeline from './Timeline'

class Profile extends Component{
    state = {
        user: {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8090/user/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
          .then(res =>{
            const user = res.data
            this.setState({ user: user })
        })
    }

    render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>This is the profile page of { this.state.user.username }.</h1>
            <img src={this.state.user.profilePicture} ></img>
            <h3> E-mailaddress: { this.state.user.mail }</h3>
            <Timeline id={this.state.user.id}/>
        </div>
    )}
}

export default Profile
```

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const cookies = new Cookies()

class Timeline extends Component {

  state = {
    user: cookies.get('user'),
    posts: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.id
    console.log("ID IS " + id)
    if (this.state.user === undefined)
      return



    axios.get(`http://localhost:8090/user/${id}/postEntities`)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        posts: response.data._embedded.post
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.user !== undefined) {
      if (this.state.posts.length <= 0) {
        return (
          <main>
            <h2>Personal timeline</h2>
            <h2>This id works: { this.props.id }</h2>
            <h6>There does not seem to be anything here..<br />Create a post and come back later!</h6>
          </main>
        )
      } else {
        return (
          <main>
            <h2>Personal timeline</h2>
            {
              this.state.posts.map(post => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    <h5>{ post.title }</h5>
                    <img src={post.pictureUrl} width="200" height="200"></img>
                    <p><i>You took this picture at { post.longitude }, { post.latitude }</i></p>
                  </div>
                )
              })
            }
          </main>
        )
      }
    }
    else {
      return (
        <h5>You need to be logged in to use this feature</h5>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default Timeline
```

The expected output in the url needs to be 2 but is undefined, the expected value in the rendered part is 2 and it outputs 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With react, the componentDidMount of children is called BEFORE the one from the parent.

So, when the componentDidMount of Timeline is called the first time, the componentDidMount of Profile has not been called, so there is no userId yet.

To avoid this problem, you should render the Timeline only when the Profile component has been mounted and when you have your user id.

So something like that in the render of Profile

```
render(){
return(
    <div>
        <h1>This is the profile page of { this.state.user.username }.</h1>
        <img src={this.state.user.profilePicture} ></img>
        <h3> E-mailaddress: { this.state.user.mail }</h3>
        {this.state.user.id && (
            <Timeline id={this.state.user.id}/>
        )}
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Works perfect and makes sense! Thank you very much Vincent!!

Answer (score 1):

Because

> this.state.user.id

only has value when function axios.get in componentDidMount has done. while function render() is called before.

So, To avoid undefined, you must set state with format:

```
state = {
    user: {id : 0} //or null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially you won't have user.id, it is coming from axios service call. In this case wait till you get response and then show timeline based on condition in render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Timeline from './Timeline'

class Profile extends Component{
    state = {
        user: {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8090/user/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
          .then(res =>{
            const user = res.data
            this.setState({ user: user })
        })
    }

    render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>This is the profile page of { this.state.user.username }.</h1>
            <img src={this.state.user.profilePicture} ></img>
            <h3> E-mailaddress: { this.state.user.mail }</h3>
            {typeof(this.state.user.id) !== 'undefined' ? <Timeline id={this.state.user.id}/> : ''}
        </div>
    )}
}

export default Profile
```

Answer (score 0):

What variable is undefined? this.state.user.id?

If so, that probably means that you start with `user: {}`, then you make a promise and then set the state. The problem is that a promise will take time to fulfill, so meanwhile you are still with `user: {}` and `this.state.user.id` gives undefined.

When you call `<Timeline id={this.state.user.id}/>` make sure you have a id and email in your state. Or define your state with `user: {is: '', email:''}` or do a conditional render. Hope I understood your problem correctly!